# how to navigate two carousel by single navigator at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

[image] There I have used 2 carousel 1st is slide to text and second is navigate image inside     mobile frame but both are not sliding same time if it will navigate by navigator then mov
live on http://ashish.net63.net I have used bootstrap carousel here if you have any other carousel for this type of alider please help me thanks in advance

```
      $(function(){
    $('.carousel-sync').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(ev) {
        $('.carousel-sync').removeClass('sliding');
    });

    $('.carousel-indicators li').on('click', function() {
      $('#myCarousel1,#myCarousel2').carousel(parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-slide-to')));
    });

    });
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">
         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                        <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-arrow carousel-arrow-prev" href="[id*=myCarousel]" data-slide="prev"> 
                                </a>
                                <a class="carousel-arrow carousel-arrow-next" href="[id*=myCarousel]" data-slide="next">    
                                </a>
                    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
2nd carousel from here

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="mo-holder img-responsive">
                    <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide carousel-sync" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">     
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="images/1screen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
                            </div>
    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: both are not sliding at same time on page load

Comment: if you post the code to your carousels I can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

         $('#carousel1').carousel({
         interval: 10000
     });

     $('#carousel2').carousel({
         interval: 10000
     });
});
```

This way both carousels will start up with an interval of 10 seconds inbetween slides.